# Query returns no records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hello i am making schema for purchasing orders these orders can be ordered by certain user and then received by another user.

so i created the below schema.

**Schema**

[image: Schema]

The issue is when `UserID` column in `PurchaseOrders` and `Deliveries` tables has different values the query returns no records.

**Query**

```
SELECT
  dbo.Users.FirstName,
  dbo.Users.LastName,
  dbo.PurchaseOrders.PurchaseOrderDate,
  dbo.Deliveries.ExpectedDeliveryDate,
  dbo.Deliveries.ActualDeliveryDate
FROM dbo.PurchaseOrders
INNER JOIN dbo.Users
  ON dbo.PurchaseOrders.UserID = dbo.Users.UserID
INNER JOIN dbo.Deliveries
  ON dbo.PurchaseOrders.PurchaseOrderID = dbo.Deliveries.PurchaseOrderID
  AND dbo.Users.UserID = dbo.PurchaseOrders.UserID
  AND dbo.Users.UserID = dbo.Deliveries.UserID
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two different joins to `Users`.  You also need to learn to use table aliases:

```
SELECT pu.FirstName as purchase_FirstName, pu.LastName as purchase_LastName,
       du.FirstName as delivery_FirstName, du.LastName as delivery_LastName,
       po.PurchaseOrderDate,
       d.ExpectedDeliveryDate, d.ActualDeliveryDate
FROM dbo.PurchaseOrders po JOIN
     dbo.Deliveries d
     ON po.PurchaseOrderID = d.PurchaseOrderID JOIN
     dbo.Users pu
     ON p.UserID = pu.UserID JOIN
     dbo.Users du
     ON d.UserId = du.UserId;
```

Your query returns no records because of this condition:

```
  AND dbo.Users.UserID = dbo.PurchaseOrders.UserID
  AND dbo.Users.UserID = dbo.Deliveries.UserID
```

This obviously means that `dbo.PurchaseOrders.UserID = dbo.Deliveries.UserID`.  So, if this is not true, then no records match the condition.

Answer (score 1):

When you use Inner Join, if the data doesnt match, you will not get any records. You need to use LEFT JOIN and also the second join doesnt need condition with user id. Try the below query.

```
SELECT
dbo.Users.FirstName,
  dbo.Users.LastName,
  dbo.PurchaseOrders.PurchaseOrderDate,
  dbo.Deliveries.ExpectedDeliveryDate,
  dbo.Deliveries.ActualDeliveryDate
FROM dbo.PurchaseOrders
INNER JOIN dbo.Users
  ON dbo.PurchaseOrders.UserID = dbo.Users.UserID
LEFT JOIN dbo.Deliveries
  ON dbo.PurchaseOrders.PurchaseOrderID = dbo.Deliveries.PurchaseOrderID
```